# Run method from class in for loop

Tags: javascript, class, for-loop, typescript, methods

I am new so I am sorry for the confusion between TypeScript and JavaScript. I am suppose to be writing in TypeScript currently. I am trying to run the method in my class through the for loop at the end of the code. I have my basic structure from Mozilla Developer Network so I am not sure if that is correct, but from what I can tell it is. Either way, like I said I want to run my method through the loop below. I believe I need to use dot notation but I cannot find the error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

TypeScript/JavaScript

```
class Employee {
    name:string;
    age:number;
    timeInJob:number;
    stillEmployed:boolean;
  constructor(name:string, age:number, timeInJob:number, stillEmployed:boolean){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.timeInJob = timeInJob;
    this.stillEmployed = stillEmployed;
  }
  get extraVacay(){
    return this.vacay();
  }
  vacay(){
    return this.age + this.timeInJob;
  }
};

let myEmployees = [];

let justin = new Employee('Justin', 25, 3, true);
myEmployees.push(justin);
let derek = new Employee('Derek', 22, 8, true);
myEmployees.push(derek);
let taylor = new Employee('Taylor', 24, 9, true);
myEmployees.push(taylor);
let eli = new Employee('Eli', 29, 10, false);
myEmployees.push(eli);
let tyler = new Employee('Tyler', 25, 7, false);
myEmployees.push(tyler);

console.log(myEmployees);
console.log(justin.extraVacay);

for (i = 0; i < myEmployees.length; i++){
  let magicNumber = Employee.extraVacay();
  console.log(magicNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. You're not getting access to the employee in your array properly.
2. You are not calling the property getter correctly:

Try this:

```
for (i = 0; i < myEmployees.length; i++){
  const employee = myEmployees[i];
  let magicNumber = employee.extraVacay;
  console.log(magicNumber);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! Do you mind explaining why we needed to create a const?

Comment: We didn't have to create a const, `let` or `var` would have also worked, but IMO the code is clearer if you use `const` for anything that doesn't change.

Comment: I think maybe a more clear way for me to ask my question is, is it possible to do that in one line...something link `let magicNumber = myEmployee[i].extraVacay;` or is that not allowed for some reason? Sorry for the newb question.

Comment: Yes, you can do it that way as well, like `const magicNumber = myEmployees[i].extraVacay;`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.